# Elasticsearch range unique aggregations doc

Tags: elasticsearch, range, aggregate

Elasticsearch 2.1.1.
The index contains records about athlete’s jumps. Each athlete has several attempts to make a jump. 
The document has the following structure:

```
{
   'event_at' : '2015-01-01T12:12:10', - date of jump
   'user_id' : 2142, - athlete’s id
   'distance' : 4 - result
}
```

It’s necessary to get the following result:

```
{'distance_range' : 
 {'*-5' : 12, - the number of unique athletes with the maximum jump score in the range from 0 to 5
  '6-10': 14,- the number of unique athletes with the maximum jump score in the range from 6 to 10
  '11-15': 5 - the number of unique athletes with the maximum jump score in the range from 11 to 15
 } 
}
```

I managed to get the maximum value of jumping score for each athlete, but I have no idea how to obtain this result on a higher level.

Using SQL it can be like this:

```
SELECT `distace_range`, count(*) FROM (
  SELECT 
    `user_id`,
    IF(MAX(`distace`) <=5, 
      '*-5', 
      IF(MAX(`distace`) >= 6 AND MAX(`distace`) >= 10,
        '6-10',
        '11-15'        
      ) 
    ) `distace_range`
  FROM `events`
  GROUP BY `user_id`
) t
GROUP BY `distace_range;
```

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using? Did you try pipeline aggregations (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html) introduced in Elasticsearch 2.x?

Comment: this problem could be solved easily, if you are willing to store max jump in your document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I published a question on the [official forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/topic/39395/3) dedicated to the Elasticsearch. At the moment, the problem can not be solved by standard instruments, because  for the following query:

```
'aggregations' => [
  'distance_range' => [
    'terms' => [
      'field' => 'doc.user_id',

    ],
    'aggregations' => [
      'max_distance' => [
        'max' => [
          'field' => 'doc.distance'
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

in the elasticsearch version 2.1 there is no pipeline aggregator  by range or term.

There are several possible approaches for solving this problem:

1. Create  an additional index containing the maximum result
2. Use scripts
3. Sum the result on the client-side

I used the third approach.

The first option has a substantial drawback: to have a relevant additional index it’s necessary to control it. Thus, I was not satisfied with this solution.

The second option also has some important limitations: 
the complexity of the calculations or impact on the selection significantly affects the access time. Moreover, we have to maintain code in multiple systems.